# php inserts HEX number of characters before the content

Tags: php, html, apache, utf-8

I'm moving a website to a new server. (Old server had php 5.3.2, the new one has php 5.5.9)
Centos, httpd Apache/2.2.26.

I've copied files and it works fine except the only weird thing:
some strange HEX number is inserted before the content of pages:

[image]

Also, in the bottom of the page, `0` is inserted after the `</html>` tag.

I've noticed two things:

1) In my case only two headers are sent from php script:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
header("Status: 200");
```

If I comment the first header than It will be ok - no strange numbers.

2) It looks like that number is the number of characters on the page (I've checked it).
And if the page is less then 8000 characters, than the number doesn't appear, but if page has 8001 characters than `1F41` appears

P.S. I was advised to remove all BOM from files. Files were OK - already without BOM. So it's not about BOM.

**UPD:**
I made a very simple test (index.php):

```
<?php header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); ?>
Lorem Ipsum ... 8000 characters
```

Everything is OK.

```
<?php header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); ?>
Lorem Ipsum ... 8001 characters
```

Bug happens `1f41` before Lorem Ipsum.

Comment: Have you tried a simple `hello world` type example? Does it still output this text?

Comment: Yes, I've tried `hello world` example. It worked ok. Then I began to build up my page (where bug exists) from the simple `hello world`. And bug happened when number of characters began > 8000 and the `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` header was sent.

Comment: by removing BOM I meant saving files in `UTF-8 without BOM` - Byte order mask

Comment: I'm just trying to rule other things out like JavaScript or some hidden thing somewhere in your PHP. Create the simplest example using nothing but the `header`s necessary and the necessary amount of [non html text](http://www.blindtextgenerator.com/lorem-ipsum) and see if it still shows up.

Comment: Maybe the source contains some odd characters. As soon as you start copying more and more pieces of your original script into the test, you might copy this accidental garbage as well. If I understand correctly, these characters should exist somewhere around position 8000.

Comment: check for white space or carriage return before the first `<?php`

Comment: @Mike I updated my post - I made a very simple example - without js, html tags, special characters, etc. Only one php header and 8001 characters (Lorem Ipsum)

Comment: @andrew, no whitespace there, I've checked

Comment: @Innuendo have you tried it in another browser just to rule out some sort of strange browser plug-in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not PHP nor a BOM. You have a problem with Content-Transfer-Encoding.

The server is sending along [a `Chunked` encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) (this is usually done when the `Content-Length` is unavailable) which the client apparently doesn't know how to handle, *or* the header combination makes the client believe that it can bypass dechunking.

Therefore, what is actually the "length of next chunk" gets interpreted by the client, and you see it as a hex bit before the content:

```
05
These
05
 Are 
03
the
1F
 first characters of the senten
03
ce.
```

instead of

```
Content-Length: 48
These are the first characters of the sentence.
```

(*I calculated the lengths by eye, they're probably wrong*)

The likely cause is that you have some kind of **buffering** which interferes with Content Encoding. If everything stays in the buffer, all well and good, a Content-Length is available, gets sent and Bob's your uncle. But if you send more than the 8000 bytes of the buffer, the buffer is flushed and something untoward happens. Try looking in the documentation for zlib and output buffering, you might have some conflict in `php.ini` between what Apache does and what PHP does.

Interesting links that show how exactly 8000 is (was?) a buffer size used in some portions of apache:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45945

https://serverfault.com/questions/366996/how-can-the-apache-2-2-deflate-module-length-limit-be-increased

This last link suggests me to suggest you to try checking whether zlib, mod_gzip, ob_gzhandler and/or mod_deflate are enabled, and possibly conflicting, or to try exchanging the one for the other.

## Update (as per comment)

> Adding the appropriate Transfer-Encoding header fixes the problem.

So what *really* happened? We know that the output was correctly chunked-encoded (i.e. the chunking *itself* was correct), and the client was able to interpret it after being told to. So what was missing was simply the *knowledge of the content being chunked*, which looks absurd and a good bit **buggy**: for whatever chunked the content had to know it would get chunked (d'oh!), so it had responsibility of adding the appropriate header, *and yet it did not* (or it did, but something else *stripped* it), until the OP rectified the situation adding a header himself by hand.

The problem is now solved, but I think there must be still a bug lingering somewhere in the workflow, either in the modules, the application, or in how the headers are processed.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to disable mod_deflate in httpd.conf and it didn't help.

Comment: `header("Transfer-Encoding: chunked");` fixes the problem. Or it's only half-solution and I need to find out what modules are conflicted?

Comment: Hmmm. This is a funny scenario. Adding to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the PHP chat [room yesterday](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/15038936#15038936) 9F 1A is the BOM for [UTF-16BE Encoding](http://www.kreativekorp.com/charset/encoding.php?file=cp936.kte&char=FC8D)

> In my case only two headers are sent from php script:
>
> header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); header("Status: 200");

What's going here? Why are you setting both? One is a proper http response, the other is a CGI response. You shouldn't need to set either, as PHP will default to a 200 OK if the script completes. And setting a CGI style header is probably wrong, unless you're definitely running PHP in CGI mode through Apache.

Comment: `9F1A` in HEX is just number `40730` in decimal - the number of characters of content. If I add one more character to content, then `9F1A` will change to `9F1B`, etc.
Why I sent both these headers? Really only yesterday I found out this - I use forked open-source framework, and those headers are default ones for html-view Response

Comment: by the way, thank you for lint script. It showed only `dangerous` functions (like `strpos`, etc), that I changed to `mb_*` analogs. Script said nothing about BOM. Also I've tried some bash scripts to check BOM/remove it if needed. It was already OK, my Sublime 3 editor saves files without BOM

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem for serving HTML as well as plain text.
EXPLICITLY setting header Transfer-Encoding to "chunked"

```
header("Transfer-Encoding: chunked");
```

indeed solved the problem (not sure how reliably though).
That Transfer-Encoding header was being added automatically even if i didn't set it - but the problem was still there. Setting the header explicitly in PHP code solved it, but not exactly - see below. Tested using websniffer.cc, PHP 7.4.9, CentOS 7.8

UPDATE: adding the header might confuse some clients. https://securityheaders.com/ failed to connect to the site with this header explicitly set on (regardless of content length)