# Random hex characters being inserted into web source code

Tags: javascript, html

Only on certain computers, but on all tested browsers (Chrome, Safari, IE and Firefox), some random hex codes are being inserted into the source code of our web pages. They seem to be about every 8000 characters and usually include a new line before and after it.  Here is a sample of a page that had the problem:

```
<td align="center" 
class="rownumber weight_row" style="font-size:23px;font-weight:bold;font-family:Garamond, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" 
id="gamepoints_
1f57
3442">1</td>
<td  align="center">
```

the correct code would look like this:

```
<td align="center" 
class="rownumber weight_row" style="font-size:23px;font-weight:bold;font-family:Garamond, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"     
id="gamepoints_3442">1</td>
<td  align="center">
```

The additional 1f57 is not in our source code, and it appears seemingly randomly throughout the page, interrupting the code at various spots.  It seems to appear every 8000 characters and is usually 1fxx, but can be 20xx or 1dxx, where xx is a hexadecimal number.  The hard part to figure out is why it only happens on a very few number of users (we have 20,000 users and I know of 4 where this is happening), and I cannot make it happen on any computer I own.  Additionally, for one person, he went to a new location and the problem stopped (flew with his laptop), so I am not sure if it related to IP addresses or not.  Any help on figuring this out would be appreciated.  These extra characters are causing the javascript code to fail on the page.

UPDATE:
The web stack is CentOS release 6.5, Apache/2.0.64, MySQL 5.1.73, PHP 5.2.9.  I have confirmed our server is using HTTP1.1 response.

UPDATE #2:
Every person having the issues is running a proxy.  It seems to be related to Transfer-Encoding: chunked. Found this on stackoverflow that suggests adding a header:

[php inserts HEX number of characters before the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121282/php-inserts-hex-number-of-characters-before-the-content)

However, when I add the header("Transfer-Encoding: chunked") to the top of the file inside of the php code, the page doesn't load.

So somehow the header is being interpreted through these proxies as not being chunk encoded.  Is there a way for me to add something on my end to make it interpret it correctly?

Comment: maybe something to do with chunked encoding? Maybe your `Content-Encoding` header is wrong. Maybe you're sending chunked encoding to clients that don't support it (really old browsers).

Comment: @Jim if you could get a capture of the requests/response with wireshark that would be helpful.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - what other info would you like me to supply?  I do know that for one person it didn't work on a brand new install of Chrome and then he flew to a new city and it worked fine there without issue.  I am trying to do some of the things Hamish suggested.  I'll post the results I get.

Comment: @Jim: The info you added to the end of the question is what I was looking for. In general, when you ask a question, it's best to stick around for a few minutes so you can reply to questions like that; it makes it more likely you'll get a useful answer. So when you hadn't replied for an hour or so, I voted to close for lack of detail (I've retracted the vote now).

Comment: Is the content of the page dynamically generated by PHP? Just trying to help figure out what layer the problem is in.

Comment: Sorry @T.J.Crowder - missed this. Yes, the page is dynamically generated by PHP. I also have found out more info - added it as updates above

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly caused by a proxy at the users end.

Without more information, my *best guess* is you are sending a HTTP1.1 response but the user's proxy is interpreting it as HTTP1.0 (either because it's really old or misconfigured).

You could test by asking them to bypass their proxy, or inspect what they're actually receiving with their debugging tools, or just force all your responses to HTTP1.0 and see what happens.

---

(if I had to put money on it, I'd say a transparent squid proxy, would love to know if I'm right!)

Comment: Thank you - I have asked them to load a page that will detect which proxy they are using and send me the results.  I'll let you know if you are right.

Comment: Here's what I now know - the people who have this issue are definitely running a proxy.  We put some code in to detect a proxy, and in every case it is there.  Where they can turn it off, it starts working correctly.  Is there something else I can do to get around their proxy?

Comment: I don't know much about these protocols and proxies.  I am a programmer so would appreciate any help you can give me.  I referred our host to this link and they said "Please note that chunked Transfer-Encoding is a HTTP/1.1 feature that is currently available on the installed version on your server. Downgrading to HTTP/1.0 is not a possible solution here, as those older version are not even supported by cPanel now. On reading the documentations, there are few options specified such as set the Content-Length on header to override chunked Transfer-Encoding."

Comment: I did set up a test page at [TestProxy](http://www.funofficepools.com/testProxy2.php).  For those having issues it detects a proxy and prints out 1000 lines.  Every 80 lines it adds a 1f23 or something like that.  This is the same symptom we are seeing on our other pages.  We did make another test page at [Second proxy test](http://www.funofficepools.com/testProxy.php).  This one has a php header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK") at the beginning and a meta http-equiv="Transfer-Encoding" content="chunked" in it, but I admit I'm grasping at straws now.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One last thing - I tried going through a public proxy, and although the pages I listed above did detect a proxy, there were no 1fxx's anywhere on the page.  I can never see the problem, no matter what network I use, but I have a small number of people (less than 1% I think) who have it.  Some see it on iphones using AT&T networks (I have the same and don't see it).  Any ideas how I could potentially simulate the issue?